# how to leverage overloading while keeping business logic out of models

Tags: java, object-oriented, polymorphism, separation-of-concerns

I am running into a conflict between two best practice principles-

1. overloading should be used instead of long chained if/else statements
2. models should not contain business logic

I am working on a chess game and am struggling on implementing my method `calculatePotentionalMoves()` for all the different types of pieces

Originally I put this abstract method inside the `Piece` parent but when I added a DB, I realized that `Piece` and all its children are POJOs. So to follow best practices I created a `PieceService`, moved the method there, and overloaded it, aka -`calculatePotentionalMoves(Queen queen)` `calculatePotentionalMoves(King king)` etc.

However I was unable to use it since I could not dynamically downcast each Piece to its subclasses without an if/else chain (or one its equivalents)

My only idea left is for the piece itself to call the method but then I either have to wire in the `PieceService` to each Piece, create a new one upon each call (the service has no dependencies), pass the service to the method, or change `PieceService` from a @Service class to a static class. What's the best practice here?

Is there a better strategy to use?

Comment: *"models should not contain business logic"* -- can you clarify what you mean by "models"? The term "model" has become generalized to mean a number of things in programming.

Comment: Also, I've *never* heard anyone say "keep business logic out of models." They usually tell me the opposite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. overloading should be used instead of long chained if/else statements

Says who? Overloading<sup>[1](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overloading-in-java/)</sup> is syntactic sugar that prevents you from having to do your own name mangling<sup>[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314743/what-is-name-mangling-and-how-does-it-work)</sup> so you can reuse the same name with different method signatures. Has nothing to do with `if`.

Are you perhaps thinking of the refactoring, "replace conditional with polymorphism"<sup>[3](https://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html)</sup>? This is not a principle. Just a refactoring that has some potential benefits: may support OCP<sup>[4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle)</sup>, may simulate a jump table<sup>[5](https://www.cipht.net/2017/10/03/are-jump-tables-always-fastest.html)</sup>, and may prevent duplicated code<sup>[6](https://wiki.c2.com/?SwitchStatementsSmell)</sup>, among others.

But no, it's not a principle. It's a judgement call. Because while it has a lot of fancy sounding benefits it also scatters a simple straight forward story into multiple files. Doing that is not free. It comes with a cost. Be sure you have a good reason to pay it.

> 2. models should not contain business logic

Models should model what they model. I think [Danny Brady said it best](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13952171/1493294)

> Generally I try to keep controllers simple in terms of logic too. If business logic is required, it will go up to 'service layer' classes to handle it. This also saves repeating any code/logic too, which ultimately makes the whole project more maintainable if business logic was to change. I just keep models purely as entity objects.
>
> I think the answer above sums it up nicely though, it is easy to over engineer a project based on design patterns: Go with whatever works for you and is most maintainable/efficient.

So it isn't that models should never contain business logic. It's whether you can find or build a better place to put it.

Now putting these ideas together I suggest the following code change:

```
Piece queen = new Queen(color);
queen.calculateLegalMoves(board, nextColorToMove, position)
```

Now that is a POJO<sup>[8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_Java_object#:%7E:text=In%20software%20engineering%2C%20a%20plain,bound%20by%20any%20special%20restriction.)</sup>. It's also DTO<sup>[9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)</sup> because it exposes it's color. It's also a behavior object<sup>[10](https://www.javatpoint.com/q/5820/difference-between-state-and-behaviour-in-object)</sup> because it can generate a list of legal moves for itself to take.

```
for (Position position : allRowColPositions) {
  piece = board.getPiece(position);
  moves = piece.calculateLegalMoves(board, nextColorToMove, position);
  legalMoves.addAll(moves);
}
```

This code is polymorphic. While it deals with pieces it has no idea what type they are. The pieces know what they are so this code doesn't have to care.

The pieces have no idea where they are until you tell them. The board knows where they are by holding a reference to them in that space. If you want to talk to a DB with this I suggest starting with a `toString` that outputs piece type as a single character and letting board deal with saving games in different notations<sup>[10](https://www.dummies.com/article/home-auto-hobbies/games/board-games/chess/understanding-chess-notation-192295/)</sup>.

Now I certainly wont say this is the only way to do this. But I did win a chess tournament with this method (but honestly what won it was doing a fanatical amount of testing to avoid making illegal moves). If you're curious [I have talked about chess here before](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/420817/131624).

Answer (score 2):

Judging by this description, you're looking for the **visitor pattern**:

> My only idea left is for the piece itself to call the method but then I either have to wire in the PieceService to each Piece, create a new one upon each call (the service has no dependencies), pass the service to the method, or change PieceService from a @Service class to a static class. What's the best practice here?

I assume you currently have a design like this:

```java
abstract class Piece { ... }
class Queen extends Piece { ... }
class Rook extends Piece { ... }
...

class PieceService {
  public Moves calculateLegalMoves(Queen q) { ... }
  public Moves calculateLegalMoves(Rook r) { ... }
  ...
  public Moves calculateLegalMoves(Piece p) {
    if (p instanceof Queen) return calculateLegalMoves((Queen) p);
    ...
  }
}
```

Indeed, you can solve this problem by having each Piece call the PieceService. But, with the help of an additional class, you can do this without creating a direct Piece→PieceService dependency. The idea is that we introduce a `PieceVisitor` interface for classes that want to do different things to each piece. Then we'd have to write the following one-time boilerplate:

```java
interface PieceVisitor<R> {
  // the methods could all be called visit() and use overloading,
  // this doesn't matter
  R visitQueen(Queen q);
  R visitRook(Rook r);
  ...
}

abstract class Piece {
  public abstract R accept<R>(PieceVisitor<R> v);
}

class Queen extends Piece {
  public R accept<R>(PieceVisitor<R> v) { return v.visitQueen(this); }
  ...
}

class Rook extends Piece {
  public R accept<R>(PieceVisitor<R> v) { return v.visitRook(this); }
  ...
}
```

Our PieceService could then implement the PieceVisitor interface. For clarity, I'll call it `LegalMoves` instead:

```java
class LegalMoves implements PieceVisitor<Moves> {
  public Moves visitQueen(Queen q) { ... }
  public Moves visitRook(Rook r) { ... }
  ...

  // convenience method for invoking the pattern:
  public static Moves of(Piece p) { return p.accept(new LegalMoves()); }
}
```

---

As to the idea that “models should not contain business logic” – eeh. There's a good debate to be had here. When you have a large matrix of behaviours × objects, both approaches to organize this code can be reasonable: grouping it by object, or grouping it by behaviour.

- Classic OOP tends to favour grouping behaviours together with the objects on which they operate (like adding a `calculateLegalMoves()` method to each piece).
- Other approaches such as functional programming or “anemic design models” tend to favour simple data definitions without behaviour, meaning that behaviours are provided outside of the class. The aforementioned visitor pattern makes it possible to keep (some) behaviours outside of an object hierarchy in an otherwise OOP-ish design.

Both of these approaches can be valid, but they enable extensibility along different dimensions. Grouping behaviours into each object makes it easy to add new object types, but difficult to add new behaviours. Keeping behaviours external makes it easy to add new behaviours, but difficult to create new objects.

Since chess features a fixed set of pieces, it is unlikely that you'll need to create new types of pieces. In contrast, it is likely that you will want to extend your chess engine with new behaviours. This would be a weak indication that classic OOP modelling wouldn't be a great fit, and keeping behaviours in service classes/visitors/anywhere else could be part of a good design.

It is worth noting that modern Java has increasingly good support for dealing with such closed object hierarchies. This example could also be written as follows, using sealed classes + pattern matching instead of a manual visitor implementation:

```java
sealed class Piece { ... }  // can only be extended in current file
class Queen extends Piece { ... }
class Rook extends Piece { ... }
...

class LegalMoves {
  public static Moves of(Piece p) {
    return switch (p) {
      Queen q -> ...;
      Rook r -> ...;
      ...
      // no "default" case needed
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I realized that `Piece` and all its children are POJOs

This logic is backwards. You shouldn't "realize" something is a POJO - you *design* it to be. And if being a POJO breaks your design, then you stop it being a POJO.